# URL not inserting properly into Outlook message body from string

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim Urll as string
urll = http://10.0.0.1/Program.exe"

.msgbody = "<a href=" & urll & ">Click here </a>" & "to open the program"
```

ends up fragmenting the HTML to where the the URL shows up as a link, but it doesn't use the "Click here" as it's text.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7471776/2654498

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to set your message as html

```
.isBodyHTML = true
```